# Foreach loop using php

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am encountering a problem when printing out the array that is stored inside `$description`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php foreach($descriptions as $description) { foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
 <div class="tabs-add language_id_<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>" id="tab-language-<?php echo $module_row; ?>-<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>">
    <table id="general" class="form">
     <tr>
        <td><?php echo $entry_title; ?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="announcement_module[<?php echo $module_row; ?>][title][<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>]" id="title-<?php echo $module_row; ?>-<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo isset($module['title'][$language['language_id']]) ? $module['title'][$language['language_id']] : ''; ?>" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $entry_description; ?> &nbsp;&nbsp;<a onclick="removeMessage(this);"><?php echo $button_remove; ?></a></td>
        <td><textarea name="announcement_module[<?php echo $module_row; ?>][description][<?php echo $description_row;?>][<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>]" id="description-<?php echo $module_row; ?>-<?php echo $description_row;?>-<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo isset($module['description'][$description_row][$language['language_id']]) ? $module['description'][$description_row][$language['language_id']] : ''; ?></textarea></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
```

I want to print out the `$entry_description` as many times the user wants. But I can't seem to print out more than one at a time. How do I solve this?

Comment: have you printed the arrays to check the content with print_r for example ?

Comment: knowing the structure of the array would help a lot, can you add it to your question?

Comment: are you sure that loops iterates more than once? do `var_dump($descriptions,$languages);`

Comment: Each iteration of the inner loop generates a new `<div>` and a new `<table>` with just two rows. Is that really what you want to do? If so the table ID will be duplicated on each new table when IDs should be unique.

Comment: Try not to mix PHP and HTML. It makes code very illegible.